# how to remove some code to an external python file

Tags: python, class, import

I have a python file, it has a short Main function and a big class. 
The main function only creates an instance of that class, and calls its `run()` function. 
The class has 7 functions, 5 of them will not be changed, and the other 2 will be changed a lot, I want to only deal with those 2 in this file.
I want to remove the 5 functions to an outside class in another file and be able to just import that class and run its functions easily.

Comment: Making a base class with the 5 functions in it, which the other class inherits should do the job for you.

Comment: What problems are you experiencing when you try to do this? Please post a minimal example of your solution and explain why it is deficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to class inheritance.

File 1:

```
class Foo():

    def foo2():
        return 2

    def foo3():
        return 3
```

Main file:

```
import file1


class Foo(file1.Foo):

    def foo1():
        return 1


print Foo.foo3()
```

Comment: Why static methods?

Comment: @wwii No importance, I just wanted to make simple functions, and it makes sense that those simple functions be static methods. I'll edit that bit out to make it simpler